# Symfony bundle directory structure - where to put service classes

Tags: php, symfony

In my Symfony 3 app I have several classes that do some kind of task, for example calculating amounts, finding things, naming directories...

Currently, they are all in Service directory, so directory structure looks something like this:

```
- AppBundle
 -- Controller
 -- Entity
 -- Form
 -- Service
   -- LiveStatsCalculator.php
   -- DirectoryNamer.php
   -- AdvertisementPlayCalendarFactory.php
   -- MediaConfigGenerator.php
   ...
```

Is this good approach, or should I separate directories, based on a task class is responsible for?
For example:

```
- AppBundle
 -- Controller
 -- Calculator
   -- LiveStatsCalculator.php
 -- Entity
 -- Factory
   -- AdvertisementPlayCalendarFactory.php
 -- Form
 -- Namer
   -- DirectoryNamer.php
```

Or, perhaps, there is even better solution? :)

Comment: First approach it's ok.

Comment: I keep all my services in 'Manager' directory. But if i need more, then one, that hanle one task type (like MessageFactory, MessageBuilder) i putting it into 'Manager/Message' directory. But it's all on your discretion. First approach is ok.

Comment: a-ha, tnx for your answers

@StephanYamilov your approach is something that I am planning to implement in the future, when number of the service classes increases

Comment: Primarily opinion based, but when naming things (and directories) you should avoid all to generic definitions like `Service`, `Manager`, `Utils`, ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to learn best practices of framework is to look how the internal framework bundles are organized.

I.e you can go to github for `symfony/framework-bundle` https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle

They have responsibility based naming solution and it is reasonable. Having all services stored in a single namespace would end in converting your service into trash can. Or you end in splitting namespaces inside your `Services` namepsace. I think it is not you want to end with.

Meaningful names and locaiton are always preferred.

Comment: responsibility based naming solution makes sense when you have 20, 30 or more service classes

but when you have 5 or 6 service classes, I think it unnecessarily adds more complexity

Comment: If you have 5-6 classes - I'm doubt you even need `Services` namespace. Look, for example `symfony/property-acess` namespace layout https://github.com/symfony/property-access